# JQuery is not firing. Windows, Local Host

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've come with hopes that I can achieve a functional answer to my series of baffle. I have tried linking my indexjs.js to my index.html using `<script type="text/javascript" src="./indexjs.js"></script>` --- yet to no avail. I have also tried inline editing such:

```
    link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./indexcss.css"/    
    script type="text/javascript"
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('div').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo('fast',0.5);
    });
$('div').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo('slow',1.0);
    });
});
```

/script

also to no avail. With sidenotes intact I have tried several JQuery installations and the plugin but receive an error code upon is finalization similar to: Windows Script Host

```
        Script: C:\Users\....\Desktop\public_html\indexjs.js
        Line: 1
        Char: 1
        Error:'document' is undefined
        Code:800A1391
        Source: Microsoft JScript runtime error
```

I have used googleajax referenceing through src ; as well as saving jquery-1.12.4 to the same public_html folder.

Comment: Your posted markup has problems! Is it the exact markup you are using. Because it does not have opening `<`  and closing `>` for link. As well as script also does not have opening `<` and closing `>`.

Comment: This could be the issue of jQuery conflict. Check complete view source of your rendered page and see weather there are multiple references of jQuery been added.

Comment: All tags are closed. I added this to show that the tags do exists, STACK does not allow for some html tags within post, i.e strict posting rules.--- Everyone. @Kundan---Im a little confused as to your response, can you break it down?

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan All tags are closed. I added this to show that the tags do exists, STACK does not allow for some html tags within post, i.e strict posting rules.--Im a little confused as to your response, can you break it down?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue is with `link` & `script` tag

Note `<` & `>`

[HTML LINK TAG](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="href="./indexcss.css">
```

[Script Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_script)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     //Rest of code
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yours also have problem. No end closing `>` in script.

Comment: How do you know that OP isn't using a template engine that doesn't require full tags?